# Rails store some attributes in redis instead of relational db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, redis

I have the following model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
 #Has rating, duration, year as database fields
 #Want to store content_rating in redis instead of database
end
```

I update the model like this:

```
 movie = Movie.find(1)
 movie.update(rating: 5, duration: 3600, year: "1955", content_rating: "PG-13")
```

Want I want is that all the db attributes(rating, duration, year) are stored in the database, and content_rating is stored in redis.

Is this possible with rails without saving content_rating manually in the after_update callback?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to have the `update` method save some attributes in the database and some others in Redis. (Unless you override it which is strongly discouraged.)

You can either manually define a setter and getter method to store and read the attribute from Redis (using the [redis-rb](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb) gem):

```rb
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def content_rating=(value)
    redis.set(content_rating_key, value)
  end

  def content_rating
    redis.get(content_rating_key)
  end

  private

  def redis
    @redis ||= Redis.new
  end

  def content_rating_key
    @content_rating_key ||= "#{self.class.table_name}:#{id}:content_rating"
  end
end
```

```rb
movie = Movie.find(1)
movie.content_rating = "PG-13"
movie.content_rating # => "PG-13"
```

Or, use the [kredis](https://github.com/rails/kredis) gem instead which makes it pretty simple:

```rb
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  kredis_string :content_rating
end
```

```rb
movie = Movie.find(1)
movie.content_rating.value = "PG-13" # Saves the attribute in Redis.
movie.content_rating.value # Reads the attribute from Redis which is now "PG-13".
```

Also, note that if you're going to iterate over movies and read their `content_rating`, it'll generate N+1 Redis queries which might become a performance bottleneck. In that case, you should use `Redis#mget` to load the attributes all at once.

Comment: "In that case, you should use Redis#mget to load the attributes all at once." - ah, but now your custom accessor goes out the window :) As you say, it's a bad idea overall.